# Связанные таблицы в C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отобразить полную схему таблицы Play Вместе с Team и Actor

.Include(e => e.Team) - работает, но как отобразить таблицу Actor не знаю

Примечание: Схема бралась из интернета, нужно лишь помощь в отображении "таких схем"

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ
Для этого нужно использовать .ThenInclude(e => e.Actor)